# React Native Get Time In Seconds From API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am running a chat application and want to implement correct timestamps on client side, even if the devices' times might be different.

For example, I have iOS device which has current time 14:00 and Android device 14:05 (while actual time might be 14:03). They are both set to manual device times so I would need to calculate their offset from server's time.

`Date` would not work in this case because it returns client time.

I couldn't find any time APIs which could help me in this case. Is there any other approach?

Comment: you can always just set timestamps server side, or you can use some sort of time API to get world time in UTC (i.e. https://www.programmableweb.com/api/world-clock)

Comment: Hi, Did you tried this https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/10-timezone-offset/